# How to use css or sass to make slanted background color

Tags: html, css, sass

How to use css or sass to make it like Button A & B

Button A
         [image: button A]
Button B
         [image: button B]

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use clip-path for that. If your looking for a place to get started try

```
<style>
.shapePoly {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 0%);
background-color: orange;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
}
</style>
```